# Xbox One Internet Explorer JavaScript Key Press

Tags: javascript, keypress, keycode, xbox

Very silly question here, just wondering if anyone knows how to detect Xbox One Controller Key Presses? I know detecting the d-pad and the right stick is just left/up/right/down keycodes. But what about triggers (Zoom in/out)?

Answer (score 0):

You cam add an event listener in the page where you want to handle the key Press.

**document.addEventListener("keydown", **displayDate**);**

displayDate is your handler where you can get access to all keydown events.